# How update the exact row of the select, on conflict?

Tags: postgresql, upsert

I need to update only when conflicts, and all the selected rows

```sql
INSERT INTO t  SELECT * FROM fdw_t
  ON CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE
     SET  id=id, etc1=etc1, etc2=etc2
; -- ERROR: column reference "id" is ambiguous

INSERT INTO t  SELECT * FROM fdw_t AS w
  ON CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE
     SET  id=w.id, etc1=w.etc1, etc2=etc2
; -- ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "w"
  -- BUT I NEED the ROW of the select, not other!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may reference the `EXCLUDED` row in the same way you would when doing an `INSERT` with a `VALUES` clause:

```
INSERT INTO t
SELECT * FROM fdw_t
ON CONFLICT (id)
DO UPDATE
SET id = EXCLUDED.id, etc1 = EXCLUDED.etc1, etc2 = EXCLUDED.etc2;
```

Comment: next problem, https://stackoverflow.com/q/64273156/287948