# ON CONFLICT clause, how to replace DO NOTHING by DO UPDATE?

Tags: postgresql, upsert

My INSERT was working with syntax

```sql
INSERT INTO t  SELECT * FROM fdw_t
  ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;
```

Now I need to change it by adding UPDATE, but **preserving all same conditctions**, how to do it?

---

This is working, but it is not "all same condictions":

```sql
INSERT INTO t
SELECT * FROM fdw_t
ON CONFLICT (id) -- why I need to add this specific and not generic condiction???
DO UPDATE
SET id = EXCLUDED.id, etc1 = EXCLUDED.etc1, etc2 = EXCLUDED.etc2;
```

I need also in UPDATE "all usable constraints", not only one constranct. The  [Guide about *conflict_target*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html#id-1.9.3.152.6.3.2) says that

> conflict_target must be provided

so, how to provide the "all usable constraints"?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, I edited. I need to preserve the same behaviour, so suppose that *all usable constraints* can be preserved as target... Need only a way to do it by explicit citation.

Comment: I do not know what you mean by *all usable constraints*, perhaps all unique constraints. But it may be a moot point anyway. On Conflict requires and permits 1 constraint and only 1 constraint as the target. You **cannot** specify more or less.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot say if this limitation is because of fundamental problems or because of implementation considerations.

You will have to resort to the traditional technique: code an endless loop that alternatively tries to `INSERT` and `UPDATE` and break out of the loop as soon as one of the operations succeeds.